# Python Password Checker Help Debugging

Tags: python, passwords

So in my computer programming class we've been tasked with making the generic password strength checker, mine works and checks the length correctly but for whatever reason the 2nd part doesn't work properly and I can't figure out why.

```
                            password = input("Please enter a password between 6 - 12 characters long: ")


                            while len(password) in range(6, 13) == False:
                                if len(password) < 6:
                                    print("Password too low!")
                                    password = input("Please enter a password between 6 - 12 characters long: ")
                                elif len(password) > 12:
                                    print("Password too high!")
                                    password = input("Please enter a password between 6 - 12 characters long: ")
                            Upper = 0
                            Lower = 0
                            Numerical = 0
                            for char in password:
                                if char == char.isupper():
                                    Upper = Upper + 1
                                elif char == char.islower():
                                    Lower = Lower + 1
                                elif char == char.isnumeric():
                                    Numerical = Numerical + 1

                            Strength = int(Upper + Lower + Numerical)

                            if Strength == 1:
                                print("Password is weak!")
                            elif Strength == 2:
                                print("Password is medium!")
                            elif Strength == 3:
                                print("Password is strong!")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I browsed other similar problems but with something specific it's kind of difficult.

EDIT: Removing the parenthesis from my while loop will do nothing, it works the same anyway. The in range part makes no difference, I still get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owen\Desktop\Password Checker.py", line 21, in 
    for char in password():

Comment: Remove parentheses `()` from your `for` loop.

Comment: Please post whatever output you are getting (including any error messages, which should include the full traceback) and explain how it differs from what you expected.

Comment: Also, `len(password)` != range(6, 12)` will always evaluate `True`. You should use `len(password) in range(6, 12)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of little issues you can fix with this section of code so I can't really tell you what is producing the improper output.

1) as Ken stated:

`len(password) != range(6, 12)` will always return true.  This is because you are comparing an int to a list.

`range(6, 12)` gives you `[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]` so the length of the password can never be equal to that statement.  However, if you use `len(password) in range(6, 12)` the length of the password is compared to each value in the list until there is a match (if there is one).  One more thing, using range(a, b) only includes numbers from a to b-1. So you really want:`len(password) in range(6, 13)`

2) The logic of the while loop should change with changes from my first point.
If `len(password) in range(6, 13)` evaluates to True, then the while statement won't loop and you will move on to the next section.  You can delete the `else` section and change your `elif` to `else`.

3) You can get rid of `LengthLow` and `LengthHigh` since you aren't using them anywhere.

4) password is a string so you can't call it with the () operator.  Your for loop should be `for char in password:`

5) Use `char.isupper()`, `char.islower()`, or `char.isnumeric()` to check if they are numeric values

6) You don't need to store `Upper`, `Lower`, and `Numerical` separately since you are just adding them together at the end anyways. You can actually accomplish this with a one liner if you are familiar with list comprehensions

```
strength = sum([1 if c.isupper() or c.islower() or c.isnumeric else 0 for c in password])
```

Although, it seems to me that this is all the same as c.isalnum() for alphanumeric. So write,

```
strength = sum([1 if c.isalnum() else 0 for c in password])
```

7) I don't know anything about password strength calculation, but I think special characters should be considered as well.  In that case `c.isalnum()` won't be the magic all in one that it is in your current code.

There may be more bugs that I haven't noticed, but that should definitely get you on your way to fixing the problem.

Comment: Thanks. A lot of that I didn't really know since I've been sort of teaching myself, it should all work now except for my while loop while len(password) != in range(6, 13): which is invalid syntax.

Comment: I'm going to edit it again since I made the changes but it still doesn't function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

ero1ca's answer explains many of the issues.

As for the last part of the code not working, that is because you loop through every char in the password, and increment based on what that character is. With a mandated length > 3, your conditional statements at the end wont cover the password!

below is a revised version of the code.

```
password = input("Please enter a password between 6 - 12 characters long: ")

while not len(password) in range(6, 13):
    if len(password) < 6:
        print ("Password too low!")
    else:
        print ("Password to high!")
    password = input("Please enter a password between 6 - 12 characters long: ")

Upper = 0
Lower = 0
Numerical = 0

if any(x.isupper() for x in password):
    Upper = 1
if any(x.islower() for x in password):
    Lower = 1
if any(x.isdigit() for x in password):
    Numerical = 1

Strength =int(Upper + Lower + Numerical)
if Strength == 1:
    print ("Password is weak!")
elif Strength == 2:
    print ("Password is medium!")
else:
    print ("Password is strong!")
```

Use raw_input instead of input() for python 2.7

*Edit* Holy Necro!  My mistake lads!